# Who is this NPC swimming outside of town borders?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

About a day ago, I saw what looked like an NPC character swimming outside of the town border. (You know, where there is a rope with things that make it float.) Now I can't find this character! Who is it?

Comment: Welcome to arqade! Two main pointers: Commentary, such as your first paragraph, should ideally be puout in comments, not the question itself. While you can not post comments to *other user's* questions (yet), you can still comment on your own post. Also, please and thankyous are not necissary, but if you want to tha k a good answer, simply upvote it, and be sure to accept the answer that best answers your question. Good luck! =)

Comment: I missed the heading, but you get the jisst. Dont use abbreviations, and make sure it makes a proper sentence or question, and you should be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a character called Pascal that does this.

http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Pascal

Plesse refer to the website under "In *Animal Crossing: New Leaf*"
I would quote this but its too long and I would not like to steal their work.

Comment: Could you maybe add a quote from it? I can not seem to understand him, and it will help everyone who maybe can't see the video then.

Comment: Watching a 20 minute video to find a five second answer isn't very reasonable.  Please quote the relevant pieces from the video.

Comment: @Frank He does have the time where it is mentioned, so he should just add a quote.